# Play akka connection Timed out

Tags: playframework, akka, connection-timeout

I have scheduled the job using play akka and facing the below issue, this is happening randomly :

```
[ERROR] [11/12/2014 08:41:29.364] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [TaskInvocation] Connection timed out
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:739)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:434)
        at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:1052)
        at org.htmlcleaner.Utils.readUrl(Utils.java:113)
        at org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner.clean(HtmlCleaner.java:359)
        at org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner.clean(HtmlCleaner.java:373)
```

Can you suggest how can I handle this exception? Or should I be increasing the timeout, not sure how to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post how you're scheduling the job? It doesn't look like Akka is throwing the exception, but rather whatever is running in the ActorSystem.

Comment: Yeah, it was happening because of HTTPClient timeout. Thanks, I have fixed it.